# Editing pyparsing parse results

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing, logfile

This is similar to a [question I've asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958427/restructuring-pyparsing-parse-results-of-multithreaded-log-file).

I have written a pyparsing grammar `logparser` for a text file which contains multiple logs. A log documents every function call and every function completion. The underlying process is multithreaded, so it is possible that a slow function `A` is called, then a fast function `B` is called and finishes almost immediately, and after that function `A` finishes and gives us its return value. Due to this, the log file is very difficult to read by hand because the call information and return value information of one function can be thousands of lines apart.

My parser is able to parse the function calls (from now on called `input_blocks`) and their return values (from now on called `output_blocks`). My parse results (`logparser.searchString(logfile)`) look like this:

```
[0]:                            # first log
  - input_blocks:
    [0]:
      - func_name: 'Foo'
      - parameters: ...
      - thread: '123'
      - timestamp_in: '12:01'
    [1]:
      - func_name: 'Bar'
      - parameters: ...
      - thread: '456'
      - timestamp_in: '12:02'
  - output_blocks:
    [0]:
      - func_name: 'Bar'
      - func_time: '1'
      - parameters: ...
      - thread: '456'
      - timestamp_out: '12:03'
    [1]:
      - func_name: 'Foo'
      - func_time: '3'
      - parameters: ...
      - thread: '123'
      - timestamp_out: '12:04'
[1]:                            # second log
    - input_blocks:
    ...

    - output_blocks:
    ...
...                             # n-th log
```

I want to solve the problem that input and output information of one function call are separated. So I want to put an `input_block` and the corresponding `output_block` into a `function_block`. My final parse results should look like this:

```
[0]:                            # first log
  - function_blocks:
    [0]:
        - input_block:
            - func_name: 'Foo'
            - parameters: ...
            - thread: '123'
            - timestamp_in: '12:01'
        - output_block:
            - func_name: 'Foo'
            - func_time: '3'
            - parameters: ...
            - thread: '123'
            - timestamp_out: '12:04'
    [1]:
        - input_block:
            - func_name: 'Bar'
            - parameters: ...
            - thread: '456'
            - timestamp_in: '12:02'
        - output_block:
            - func_name: 'Bar'
            - func_time: '1'
            - parameters: ...
            - thread: '456'
            - timestamp_out: '12:03'
[1]:                            # second log
    - function_blocks:
    [0]: ...
    [1]: ...
...                             # n-th log
```

To achieve this, I define a function `rearrange` which iterates through `input_blocks` and `output_blocks` and checks whether `func_name`, `thread`, and the timestamps match. However, moving the matching blocks into one `function_block` is the part I am missing. I then set this function as parse action for the log grammar: `logparser.setParseAction(rearrange)`

```
def rearrange(log_token):
    for input_block in log_token.input_blocks:
        for output_block in log_token.output_blocks:
            if (output_block.func_name == input_block.func_name
                and output_block.thread == input_block.thread
                and check_timestamp(output_block.timestamp_out,
                                    output_block.func_time,
                                    input_block.timestamp_in):
                # output_block and input_block match -> put them in a function_block
                # modify log_token
    return log_token
```

**My question is:** How do I put the matching `output_block` and `input_block` in a `function_block` in a way that I still enjoy the easy access methods of `pyparsing.ParseResults`?

My idea looks like this:

```
def rearrange(log_token):
    # define a new ParseResults object in which I store matching input & output blocks
    function_blocks = pp.ParseResults(name='function_blocks')

    # find matching blocks
    for input_block in log_token.input_blocks:
        for output_block in log_token.output_blocks:
            if (output_block.func_name == input_block.func_name
                and output_block.thread == input_block.thread
                and check_timestamp(output_block.timestamp_out,
                                    output_block.func_time,
                                    input_block.timestamp_in):
                # output_block and input_block match -> put them in a function_block
                function_blocks.append(input_block.pop() + output_block.pop())  # this addition causes a maximum recursion error?
    log_token.append(function_blocks)
    return log_token
```

This doesn't work though. The addition causes a maximum recursion error and the `.pop()` doesn't work as expected. It doesn't pop the whole block, it just pops the last entry in that block. Also, it doesn't actually remove that entry either, it justs removes it from the list, but it's still accessible by its results name.

It's also possible that some of the`input_blocks` don't have a corresponding `output_block` (for example if the process crashes before all functions can finish). So my parse results should have the attributes `input_blocks`, `output_blocks` (for the spare blocks), and `function_blocks` (for the matching blocks).

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

I made a simpler example to show my problem. Also, I experimented around and have a solution which kind of works but is a bit messy. I must admit there was a lot of trial-and-error included because I neither found documentation on nor can make sense of the inner workings of `ParseResults` and how to properly create my own nested `ParseResults`-structure.

```
from pyparsing import *

def main():
    log_data = '''\
    Func1_in
    Func2_in
    Func2_out
    Func1_out
    Func3_in'''

    ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(Suppress)
    input_block = Group(Word(alphanums)('func_name') + '_in').setResultsName('input_blocks', listAllMatches=True)
    output_block = Group(Word(alphanums)('func_name') +'_out').setResultsName('output_blocks', listAllMatches=True)
    log = OneOrMore(input_block | output_block)

    parse_results = log.parseString(log_data)
    print('***** before rearranging *****')
    print(parse_results.dump())

    parse_results = rearrange(parse_results)
    print('***** after rearranging *****')
    print(parse_results.dump())

def rearrange(log_token):
    function_blocks = list()

    for input_block in log_token.input_blocks:
        for output_block in log_token.output_blocks:
            if input_block.func_name == output_block.func_name:
              # found two matching blocks! now put them in a function_block
              # and delete them from their original positions in log_token
                # I have to do both __setitem__ and .append so it shows up in the dict and in the list
                # and .copy() is necessary because I delete the original objects later
                tmp_function_block = ParseResults()
                tmp_function_block.__setitem__('input', input_block.copy())
                tmp_function_block.append(input_block.copy())
                tmp_function_block.__setitem__('output', output_block.copy())
                tmp_function_block.append(output_block.copy())
                function_block = ParseResults(name='function_blocks', toklist=tmp_function_block, asList=True,
                                              modal=False)  # I have no idea what modal and asList do, this was trial-and-error until I got acceptable output
                del function_block['input'], function_block['output']  # remove duplicate data

                function_blocks.append(function_block)
                # delete from original position in log_token
                input_block.clear()
                output_block.clear()
    log_token.__setitem__('function_blocks', sum(function_blocks))
    return log_token


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
***** before rearranging *****
[['Func1'], ['Func2'], ['Func2'], ['Func1'], ['Func3']]
- input_blocks: [['Func1'], ['Func2'], ['Func3']]
  [0]:
    ['Func1']
    - func_name: 'Func1'
  [1]:
    ['Func2']
    - func_name: 'Func2'
  [2]:
    ['Func3']
    - func_name: 'Func3'
- output_blocks: [['Func2'], ['Func1']]
  [0]:
    ['Func2']
    - func_name: 'Func2'
  [1]:
    ['Func1']
    - func_name: 'Func1'
***** after rearranging *****
[[], [], [], [], ['Func3']]
- function_blocks: [['Func1'], ['Func1'], ['Func2'], ['Func2'], [], []]   # why is this duplicated? I just want the inner function_blocks!
  - function_blocks: [[['Func1'], ['Func1']], [['Func2'], ['Func2']], [[], []]]
    [0]:
      [['Func1'], ['Func1']]
      - input: ['Func1']
        - func_name: 'Func1'
      - output: ['Func1']
        - func_name: 'Func1'
    [1]:
      [['Func2'], ['Func2']]
      - input: ['Func2']
        - func_name: 'Func2'
      - output: ['Func2']
        - func_name: 'Func2'
    [2]:                              # where does this come from?
      [[], []]
      - input: []
      - output: []
- input_blocks: [[], [], ['Func3']]
  [0]:                                # how do I delete these indexes?
    []                                #  I think I only cleared their contents
  [1]:
    []
  [2]:
    ['Func3']
    - func_name: 'Func3'
- output_blocks: [[], []]
  [0]:
    []
  [1]:
    []
```

Comment: Tip #1 - use `pyparsing_common.integer` to parse `func_time` and `thread` so that they will be auto-converted to ints. #2 - are the timestamps in 24 hour time? If so you'll be able to do sorting lexically, so no need to covert to `datetime.time`s, but you may want to anyway - easy parse action. Otherwise, this looks like a lot of complexity in a parse action, especially if you might need to match output blocks from one log with input blocks from another (if logs rollover, for instance), better choice is a post-parsing func to build the desired structure from stitching blocks fm parsed results.

Comment: Maybe use a `defaultdict(list)` to collect input/output blocks (mark them so you can easily tell them apart, or just infer from presence of `timestamp_in` if input or output) keyed by func name and thread, sort the blocks by timestamp, then walk the list gathering input, output, input, output, input, input (ha! no output for that last one), etc.

Comment: `pop()` defaults to removing the last item (same as for Python lists). To pop a specific item, reference its numeric index, as in `pop(3)`.

Comment: Also note that one should not pop() items from a sequence while iterating over said sequence.

Comment: @PaulMcG thanks for your input. I have edited my post and added another example and a solution which kind of works but has some room for improvement. Could you please have a look at that?

Comment: The logs luckily don't rollover, so I don't have to match output blocks from one log with input blocks from another log.
Thanks for the defaultdict(list) idea, that does work, however there is a major problem with that approach:

Comment: The log monitor allows you to modify its logging behavior. You can set it up in a way that it logs the input_blocks of a particular function, but never their output_blocks because they aren’t interesting. So there are some logs where you have thousands of spare input_blocks without matching output_blocks. So it’s more efficient (memory-wise and coding-wise) to just look for matching blocks inside the log_parse_results, move them together in a function_block, and leave the spare input_blocks and output_blocks where they are. With the defaultdict approach you'd have to copy the spare blocks .

Comment: Also, I really like the `ParseResults.dump` method which I would lose using the defaultdict approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of `rearrange` addresses most of the issues I see in your example:

```
def rearrange(log_token):
    function_blocks = list()

    for input_block in log_token.input_blocks:
        # look for match among output blocks that have not been cleared
        for output_block in filter(None, log_token.output_blocks):

            if input_block.func_name == output_block.func_name:
                # found two matching blocks! now put them in a function_block
                # and clear them from in their original positions in log_token

                # create rearranged block, first with a list of the two blocks
                # instead of append()'ing, just initialize with a list containing
                # the two block copies
                tmp_function_block = ParseResults([input_block.copy(), output_block.copy()])

                # now assign the blocks by name
                # x.__setitem__(key, value) is the same as x[key] = value
                tmp_function_block['input'] = tmp_function_block[0]
                tmp_function_block['output'] = tmp_function_block[1]

                # wrap that all in another ParseResults, as if we had matched a Group
                function_block = ParseResults(name='function_blocks', toklist=tmp_function_block, asList=True,
                                              modal=False)  # I have no idea what modal and asList do, this was trial-and-error until I got acceptable output

                del function_block['input'], function_block['output']  # remove duplicate name references

                function_blocks.append(function_block)
                # clear blocks in their original positions in log_token, so they won't be matched any more
                input_block.clear()
                output_block.clear()

                # match found, no need to keep going looking for a matching output block 
                break

    # find all input blocks that weren't cleared (had matching output blocks) and append as input-only blocks
    for input_block in filter(None, log_token.input_blocks):
        # no matching output for this input
        tmp_function_block = ParseResults([input_block.copy()])
        tmp_function_block['input'] = tmp_function_block[0]
        function_block = ParseResults(name='function_blocks', toklist=tmp_function_block, asList=True,
                                      modal=False)  # I have no idea what modal and asList do, this was trial-and-error until I got acceptable output
        del function_block['input']  # remove duplicate data
        function_blocks.append(function_block)
        input_block.clear()

    # clean out log_token, and reload with rearranged function blocks
    log_token.clear()
    log_token.extend(function_blocks)
    log_token['function_blocks'] =  sum(function_blocks)

    return log_token
```

And since this takes the input token and returns the rearranged tokens, you *can* make it a parse action as-is:

```
    # trailing '*' on the results name is equivalent to listAllMatches=True
    input_block = Group(Word(alphanums)('func_name') + '_in')('input_blocks*')
    output_block = Group(Word(alphanums)('func_name') +'_out')('output_blocks*')
    log = OneOrMore(input_block | output_block)
    log.addParseAction(rearrange)
```

Since `rearrange` updated `log_token` in place, if you make it a parse action, the ending `return` statement would be unnecessary.

It is interesting how you were able to update the list in-place by clearing those blocks that you had found matches for - very clever.

Generally, the assembly of tokens into `ParseResults` is an internal function, so the docs are light on this topic. I was just looking through the module docs and I don't really see a good home for this topic.

Comment: This puts all the unmatched input blocks at the end. Before calling `sum()`, you could sort the blocks in your original problem using  `function_blocks.sort(key=lambda fnblk: fnblk.input.timestamp_in)`

Answer (score 0):

another demo for pyparsing setParseAction:
remove whitespace before the first value, preserve whitespace between values

i tried to solve this with `pp.Optional(pp.White(' \t')).suppress()`
but then i got `a = ["b=1"]` (parser did not stop at end-of-line)

```py
def lstrip_first_value(src, loc, token):
    "remove whitespace before first value"
    # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51335710/10440128

    if token == []:
        return token

    # update the values
    copy = token[:]
    copy[0] = copy[0].lstrip()
    if copy[0] == "" and len(copy) > 1:
        copy = copy[1:]

    # update the token
    token.clear()
    token.extend(copy)
    token["value"] = copy
    return token

Values = (
    pp.OneOrMore(Value.leaveWhitespace())
    | pp.Empty().setParseAction(pp.replaceWith(""))
)("value").setParseAction(lstrip_first_value)

Value = pp.Combine(
    pp.QuotedString(quoteChar='"', escChar="\\")
    | pp.White(' \t') # parse whitespace to separate token
)
```

inputs

```
a=
b=2
```

```
a =  
b=2
```

the values of a should always be `[""]`